# By default, the server runs a writing document instead of the browser

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I tried to change the run through the folder without success.

'jupyter notebook --generate-config'

I signed up and changed the target address and still when I register in CMD jupyter notebook I ran a writing document

Suggestions for a solution please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The problem was solved**, the default file for html beats was assigned to the writer.
All that had to be done was:
My Computer> Properties> Search Bar: Set Default Apps> Search Explorer> In html extension redefine Explorer.

Hope I helped those who also encountered this stupid problem, long before they got into the core of Jupiter's code